# Pandas Dataframe keep rows where values of 2 columns are in a list of couples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of couples :

```
year_month = [(2020,8), (2021,1), (2021,6)]
```

and a dataframe `df`

```
| ID | Year | Month |
| 1  | 2020 | 1     |
|       ...         |
| 1  | 2020 | 12    |
| 1  | 2021 | 1     |
|       ...         |
| 1  | 2021 | 12    |
| 2  | 2020 | 1     |
|       ...         |
| 2  | 2020 | 12    |
| 2  | 2021 | 1     |
|       ...         |
| 2  | 2021 | 12    |
| 3  | 2021 | 1     |
|       ...         |
```

I want to select rows where Year and Month are corresponding to one of the couples in the `year_month` list :

Output `df` :

```
| ID | Year | Month |
| 1  | 2020 | 8     |
| 1  | 2021 | 1     |
| 1  | 2021 | 6     |
| 2  | 2020 | 8     |
| 2  | 2021 | 1     |
| 2  | 2021 | 6     |
| 3  | 2020 | 8     |
|       ...         |
```

Any idea on how to automate it, so I have only to change `year_month` couples ?
I want to put many couples in `year_month`, so I want to keep a list of couples, and not to list all possibilities in df :

I **don't want** to do such :

```
df = df[((df['Year'] == 2020) & (df['Month'] == 8)) |
 ((df['Year'] == 2021) & (df['Month'] == 1)) | ((df['Year'] == 2021) & (df['Month'] == 6))]
```

Comment: Sorry, do you want the years and months individually to be evaluated, or as year-month pairs as below? For example keep all rows with 2020 in Year, or the ones that also say 8 in Month?

Comment: I want all rows having 2020 in Year AND 8 in month. I won't take 2021-8. I won't take 2020-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and filter your dataframe with your list of tuples as below:

```
year_month = [(2020,8), (2021,1), (2021,6)]
df[[i in year_month for i in zip(df.Year,df.Month)]]
```

Which gives only the paired values back:

```
   ID  Year  Month
2   1  2021      1
6   2  2021      1
8   3  2021      1
```

Comment: Excellent tip, thanks for the pointer. Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.merge`:

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(year_month, columns=["Year", "Month"]))
```

Output:

```
   ID  Year  Month
0   1  2021      1
1   2  2021      1
2   3  2021      1
```

Comment: Also works perfectly as I wanted, thanks !